# Is there a hotkey for the general "Next Move" button?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm looking for a keyboard hotkey for the generalized "Next Move", "Choose Research", "Unit Waiting for Order" button in the bottom-right corner of the interface.

Unfortunately there isn't one listed in the tooltip like for other UI elements. Is there one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, apparently <kbd>Enter</kbd> works for "Unit Needs Orders" and "Next Turn", but haven't found one for "Choose Research" or "Choose Production".

Comment: I could use the answer for Choose Research, Choose Production, and some others.  Also, `Enter` didn't work for me to cycle to the unit that needs orders when the button says "Unit Needs Orders".  I'm on a Mac, so maybe it's different.

Answer (score 4):

By default the hotkeys are somewhat limited. As you know, <kbd>Enter</kbd> is used for "Unit Needs Orders" and "Next Turn".

You can use some other hotkeys can be used for specific actions.

<kbd>F5</kbd> brings up Social Policies

<kbd>F6</kbd> will bring up the full Technology Tree (for research)

There is no hotkey for Choose Production

An alternative solution is to use [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).

The following autohotkey script will, when Civ 5 is running, cause <kbd>z</kbd> (which is unused by civ 5) to trigger a click on the "Next Move" button. The **1750**, **860** values correspond to the button's position on a 1920x1080 resolution.

```
#IfWinActive, Sid Meier's Civilization V (DX11)
z::
 {
   mousegetpos, start_x, start_y
   mouseclick, left, 1750, 860, 1, 0
   mousemove, %start_x%, %start_y%, 0
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Autohotkey is the easiest way as you showed - for those with 1440p use the following mouseclick, left, 2380, 1217, 1, 0

Comment: The AutoHotkey solution is beautiful, never even considered using it to click screen controls... Seems to work very well so far.

Comment: Late to the party, but in 2023 AutoHotkey has been updated to v2 which causes some of these commands to fail. Updated this script in a new answer here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/402330/66891. Thanks for this @Angzuril!

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution for Linux using xdotool

create a file like "/home/alexey/civ5hotkeys.sh" (or any name/location you prefer) with this context:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval "$(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)"
xdotool mousemove 2500 1230 click 1
xdotool mousemove --screen $SCREEN $X $Y
```

this will save current cursor position, move mouse and perform the click, then restore the previous cursor position.

you can also mark it executable by running "chmod +x civ5hotkeys.sh"

note that you will need to adjust 2500 and 1140 to whatever screen resolution you have. these numbers are valid for 2560*14000 screen to point to "next action" area.
(geez, really, Civilization developers - was it so hard to add a shortcut for the most often used action that people perform thousands of times??)

anyway, then create a custom shortcut in "Keyboard" settings, give it any name and point to the new file as "location". then assign any hotkey to it, e.g. CTRL+ALT+X or whatever you want, just make sure it does not conflict with any other shortcuts you use on your computer.

then you can use that shortcut during the game.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Angzuril's brilliant [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/260688/66891), AutoHotkey has been updated to v2 which means some of the commands in the answer no longer work.

The updated version for AHK v2 is:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#HotIf WinActive("ahk_exe CivilizationV_DX11.exe")
z::
{
  SendMode "InputThenPlay"
  MouseGetPos &start_x, &start_y
  Click 1750, 860
  MouseMove start_x, start_y, 0
}
```

Use `Click 2380, 1217` for 1440p. I also prefer to use an extra mouse button instead of Z (the 'browser forward' button), so I map it to `XButton2::`. List of keys available [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/KeyList.htm).