# Is there a hot-key for Next Turn in Civilization 5

Tags: civilization-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a hotkey for the general “Next Move” button?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/is-there-a-hotkey-for-the-general-next-move-button)

When all my units have acted, is there a hot key for *Next Turn*?

Do I have to click on the button with the mouse?

Comment: It looks like this question - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/is-there-a-hotkey-for-the-general-next-move-button - may have been the one you meant to link. It seems to be an exact dupe.

Comment: Since once all of your units have moved (and other things taken care of) that button changes to be the next turn button, [this other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/) covers it completely. If you believe the accepted answer there is wrong please add a comment there. If you think I'm wrong and this is not a duplicate, please edit this question to clarify what you mean. Also, you might also be interested in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8244/), which asks for something else but is related.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, pressing "enter" should do the trick.